# Magento with Magmi - Remove unwanted numbers on product update

Tags: magento, csv, import, magento-1.7, magmi

After updating our 6k+ products in Magento 1.7 using CSV import with Magmi the url_keys for all product get 4-digit numbers as suffix.

e.g. before it was www.domain.com/productname.html 
after update it's www.dmain.com/productname-5363.html

This happens although the url_key in CSV is set as "productname"

Only way to fix it is to clear all urls from database and reindex - but after next import it's happening again.

Has anyone an idea how to prevent this on import?

Answer (score 0):

The number suffix will be added when one or more url's get the same url. Since that is not possible Magento adds the suffix. Do you know if this occurs?

- You try to make product names unique before processing. For example adding a color or a model or something else from your datasource
- Or you could automate the step of emptying and reindexing the core_resource table (also take a look at the Magmi plugin On the fly indexer)